# How to deal with missing values in time series data wiser?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, time-series

Here is the case:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from itertools import repeat

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(start='2013-01-01', periods=10, freq='H'), 'value': np.random.multivariate_normal(list(repeat(0,10)), np.identity(10)), 'volume': np.random.multivariate_normal(list(repeat(0,10)), np.identity(10))})

df.loc[0:1, ['value', 'volume']] = np.nan
df.loc[6, 'value'] = np.nan
df.loc[9, 'value'] = np.nan
```

I am simply wondering how we can use linear interpolation or any reasonable methods for such a case, since there are two np.nan in the first two rows. Another problem is how to fill in missing values simultaneously in multiple columns all by linear interpolation or any other wiser ways.

Comment: Filling in missing values between two valid values is interpolation and it's easy with Pandas. However, filling in missing values at the beginning or end is an extrapolation and you should treat it differently (Machine Learning, Fit function, etc)

Comment: @Corralien Thx, so that means we may need to write a function to decide what case it is to fill the missing values.

Comment: Whatever happens you can run an interpolation on your dataframe then run an extrapolation on the remaining missing values.

Comment: Interpolation and extrapolation are potentially viable, but it very much depends on what you're doing. For some summary statistics and probabilistic analyses, interpolation will introduce bias. There is not one correct solution that applies to all cases. If you give (much) more context on what specifically these data are and what you intend on doing with them, a solution might be possible.

Comment: @Corralien I might be stupid in programming. Do you mean something like df.interpolate(method = 'spline', order = 1, limit_direction = "both") or any other built-in functions, say df.extrapolate (I did not find this in the documentation)?

Comment: @Reinderien Thx, you are right. I might consider the filling issue way too simple.

Comment: Unfortunately, such a method does not exist. Extrapolation (and even interpolation when many values are missing) requires context and a good understanding of the data.

Comment: @Corralien Thx for reminding me of this. I might be too naive in considering the problem.